# Trigger blur on select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I was wondering if there is a way to trigger blur on a `select2 v3.5.2`. I know `v4.0` is out, however I am not at a position where I can perform an upgrade to the latest version.

On another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18834044/2310818), I discovered a (undocumented possibly) way of gaining focus on select2:

```
$(mySelect).select2('focus');
```

So I am wondering if there is a way of doing:

```
$(mySelect).select2('blur');
```

Comment: $(mySelect).trigger('blur'); doesnt work?

Comment: Nope I tried that already. Should I upload a JsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.select2-container-active').removeClass('select2-container-active');
    $(':focus').blur();
}, 1);
```

Hope this helps.