# Need to open select2 dropown on button click - not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a multi select dropdown box in bootstrap and what I need is:

On button click I need to open the dropdown just like clicking the dropdown:

I have done as follows:

```
$("#multipleSelectExample").focus();
```

Fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/22/)

I want to fire ALT+ Down arrow on click button on drop down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select2 force focus on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641033/select2-force-focus-on-page-load)

Comment: Answer already here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16641154/2181514  updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n4n5Y/24/

Answer (score 3):

In your fiddle's example, you are targetting the wrong element's id, try this it should work :

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#multipleSelectExample").select2();


        $("#btn_id").click(function(){ 
            $("#multipleSelectExample").select2("open");
        });
    }

);
```