# Unable to set tabindex of inner elements of modal

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, tabindex

I want to set the tabindex of select option and plus sign(fa-plus) in my modal. I have tried tabindex="1". The problem is that the select receives the focus, but I'm unable to type anything for the option vales. Also, the plus sign, doesn't receive any focus.

Following is my code:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="matnr_name_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" >
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <!--<h4 class="modal-title" >Material Name</h4>-->
                     <div class=" form-group required col-md-12 pull-right" >
                        <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">{!!Form::label('type', 'Category');!!}</div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control nopadding select2 type " id="type" name="type">
                                <option value="">Select Type</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 nopadding">
                            <a class="" style="color: green;" target="_blank" href="<?php echo url('add_category');?>"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body"  style="height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class="pull-left">Code:-<strong><span class="ccode"></span></strong></p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary create_name">Create</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see this working in a codepen. 
But by the looks of it, I think you are using select 2 plugin for typeahead functionality in your select boxes. 
Since the plugin hides the select box and replaces it with a custom ui, you would need programmatic access to trigger it to open on focus.

- [Select 2 Opening a dropdown - documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#opening-the-dropdown)
- [Stackexchange
  Question similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641033/select2-force-focus-on-page-load)